# Firebase rules: still not safe after implementing auth

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have these rules in my Firebase Real-time Database:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read":"auth !== null && auth.uid === 'my_uid'",
      ".write": false
  }
}
```

When I try to read the data without authentication, access is denied. So far, only my app can read it successfully.

Still, I'm getting an email from time to time, from Firebase, that my rules are not secure and that everyone can read the data.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The rules you have in your question should not trigger that email. Are you sure it's coming from this project, and after you updated the rules? Keep in mind it may take a day or so for Firebase to stop alerting you after you change the rules.

Comment: It is from the correct project and the rules are saved 2 days ago, the mail arrived yesterday. I will write here if I receive it again. @FrankvanPuffelen